# When to use $\in$ and $\subseteq$ when talking about bases and topologies

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, terminology, definition

> **Can someone demonstrate a concrete example of when to use $\in$ and $\subseteq$ when talking about topologies and bases?**

*When is something $\subset$ of a basis or a topology and when is something $\in$ basis or topology?*

---

I am learning topology and getting super confused with (sometimes) seemingly arbitrary interchangeability of $\in$ and $\subseteq$ which causes me to have trouble with basic proofs.

For example, in the definition of a topology generated by a basis:

$$\tau_\mathcal{B} = \{U \subseteq X| \forall x \in U, \exists B \in \mathcal{B} \text{ s.t. } x \in B \subseteq U\}$$

> Let $B_x$ be the basis element associated with $x \in U$, then is:
>   $$\bigcup_{x \in U} B_x \in \mathcal{B} \text{ or } \bigcup_{x \in U}
>  B_x \subseteq \mathcal{B}?$$

Also

> should we write $\mathcal{B} \in \tau_\mathcal{B}$ or $\mathcal{B}
>  \subset  \tau_\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: There are not interchangeable at all. One symbol mean "belongs to" and the other "is contained in". The first is related to **elements** of a set, and the other is related to **subsets** of a set. To answer your question: $B_x\in \mathfrak B$ because $\mathfrak B$ is a **collection** of subsets of the space. And $\mathfrak B\subset \tau$ because the first is a subcollection of the topology.

Comment: It should be $\in$ in the first one and $\subset$ in the second one. It is important to keep in mind whether you're talking about a *set* or a *collection of sets*. For your first example, we're taking a union of basis elements (which are sets in the space!), so if we take a union of them, we get back a set. $\mathcal{B}$ is a *set of sets* though. For the second example, both $\mathcal{B}$ and $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ are collections of sets.

Comment: Your first use of $\in$ is incorrect. The formula which starts $$\tau_\mathcal{B} = \{U \in X|...$$ should be $$\tau_\mathcal{B} = \{U \subseteq X|...$$

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for pointint it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hoping to see this more clearly, let's start with an example. Consider $\tau$ the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$, that is to say the topology induced by the distant $d(x,y) := |x-y|$.

The open interval $(1,2)$ is an element of the topology $\tau$ for any, i.e. $(1,2)$ is open. Therefore $(1,2) \in \tau$. More generally, any interval of the form $(n,n+1)$ is in $\tau$. That is to say  $(n,n+1) \in \tau$ for any fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore
$$ \big\{ (n,n+1) :~~ n \in \mathbb{N}\big\} \subseteq \tau$$
since the set on the left is a collection of open sets.

Now you probably know that any countable union of open sets is open. Therefore
$\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(n, n+1) \in \tau$.

To sum up $\big\{ (n,n+1) :~~ n \in \mathbb{N}\big\}$ is a **subset**  of $\tau$ since it is **a collection** of open sets whereas $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(n, n+1)$ is an **element** of $\tau$ since it is **an open set**.